# Want someone to do

Tags: sentence-meaning

> He wants her to trust him

What does this sentence mean exactly?
Can three meanings written right below be implied at once without adding more contexts?

1. He wants to believe that she trusts him.
2. He strongly hopes that she will trust him.
3. He wishes that she would trust him.

Answer (score 3):

To say that **he wants** her to trust him is to say he desires her to have confidence in him - whether in his judgement, his integrity, reliability or whatever.

It is very close to saying that **he hopes for** and **he wishes to have** her trust. These are slightly different ways of expressing the same idea.

To say that **he wants to believe that she trusts him** is implied but it's a step further away from hopes and wishes. It raises questions beyond his simple declared need for her to trust him.

Comment: As a little off topic, could this sentence "I don't want the news to be real" mean similar to either "I wouldn't believe that the news is real" or "I wouldn't believe the news to be real"?

I feel that there isn't much difference in conveying the main idea, although "want" sentence seems to a little more emphasize the meaning.

Comment: *I don't want the news to be real* could have several different meanings. Two that immediately come to mind are (1) *I see things on the news I find so disturbing that I wish they weren't true*, and (2) *I don't care whether news reporters check their facts or not.* Doubtless there could be other "implied nuances" in a variety of different contexts.